# Compute Expectation and Variance of number of records

Tags: elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

I should solve the following:

*Let $X_i,...,X_n$ be independent random variables such that for any i, j, i$\neq$j: $P(X_i=X_j) = 0$. Then, $X_i$ is an upper record iff $X_i > max$ {$X_1,X_2,...,X_{i-1}$}.*

*So, $R_n = Y_1 + Y_2 + ... Y_n$ denotes the number of upper records in a sequence, here Y_i = (i) 1 if $X_i$ is a upper record and (ii) 0 otherwise (Indicator-Function).*

*Tasks:*

1. *Compute $E(R_n)$ and the limit of $E(R_n)$. Interpret the last limit result. How looks the probability space for this setup?*
2. *What is the variance $V(R_n)$ of the total number of upper records $R_n$?*

**EDIT**

@1:

$P(X_i = record)$ = ?

By permutations: In a sequence of n values $X_1,...,X_n$ there are n! permutations (= ways, to mix them). If $X_n$ = max, then there are (n-1)! permutations for the remaining $X_1,...,X_{n-1}$.

Probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P$) for $R_n$:

$\bullet$ $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,...\} = \mathbb N_{>0}$ ($0$ not included because $X_1$ is always a record and therefore $Y_1$ = $1$)

$\bullet$ $\mathcal F = P(\mathbb N_{>0}) $ (Powerset with $2^{N_{>0}} possibilities)$

$\bullet$ $\mu=\Sigma^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{i}$ ??

$E(R_n) = E(\Sigma^{n}_{i = 1} Y_i) = E(\Sigma^{n}_{i=1} \mathcal I_{x_i = record}) = \Sigma^{n}_{i = 1}E(\mathcal I_{x_i = record}) = \Sigma^{n}_{i = 1} \frac{1}{i} $

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \Sigma^{n}_{i = 1}$ $1 \over i$ = $\infty$ (harmonic series)

Interpretation of limes: The expectation exists, but is infinite, so one could argue, that's because we do not know how many records we will have in the future. Further we have learnt, that an absolute convergence is enough for an expectation, meaning, the expectation can still be infinite, but existing.

@2:

$Var(R_n) = Var(\Sigma^{n}_{i=1} Y_i) = Var(\Sigma^{n}_{i=1} \mathcal I_{x_i = record}) = \Sigma^{n}_{i=1} Var(\mathcal I_{x_i = record}) = \Sigma^{n}_{i=1} (\frac{1}{n} * (1 - \frac{1}{n})) = \Sigma^{n}_{i=1}(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2})$

Comment: 1. You've a definition of what it means for $\ X_i\ $ to be an *upper* record, but not if what it means for it to be a *record*. But $\ R_n\ $ is defined to be the number of *records* amongst $\ X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\ $.  Should this be the number of *upper* records amongst $\ X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\ $?

Comment: 2. Are $\ X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\ $ *identically distributed*?  If so, I believe the problem is easily solvable, because then $\ P(X_i>X_j)=\frac{1}{2}\ $ for $\ i\ne j\ $. If *not*, you'd have to know the distributions of the $\ X_i\ $ to have any hope of answering the questions.

Comment: @ 1. I think this should mean in both cases an upper record.

Comment: @ 2. No, that's part of the problem I think. Every $X_i$ has another probability to be an upper record. And unfortenately i have no additional instructions. So I have to come up with the probability and it's probability function by myself...

Comment: In that case you have no basis for assuming anything more about $\ P(X_i>X_j)\ $ than that it's some arbitrary number $\ \pi_{ij}\ $ between $\ 0\ $ and $\ 1\ $.  You can express $\ E(R_n)\ $ as a sum of products of the $\ \pi_{ij}\ $, but you'll then have no reason to suppose that $\ E(R_n)\ $ converges as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $. While you could write down an expression for the variance of $\ R_n\ $,  it will be rather convoluted and not very informative.

Comment: I edited my "solution" after rethinking the (sum of) probabilities. I think, the probability for $X_i$ to be a record and therefore $Y_i=1$ is 1/n (as stated already in related questions). So the sum of all possible probabilities for $Y_i$ is 1/n + (1-1/n) = 1. So $R_n$ is just the sum over all possible records.

Comment: From the information you've provided you have no basis for assuming that the probability of $\ X_n\ $ being an upper record is $\ \frac{1}{n}\ $.  That *would be* the case if the $\ X_i\ $  were *identically distributed*, but you've explicitly ruled that out.